# express handle multiple levels of req params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my express app I want the below routes.

`/regions`

`/regions/europe`

`/regions/europe/france`

`/regions/europe/france/paris`

I currently have this working with the below setup but was wondering if there was a more concise approach? eg can you handle this all in one server.get?

At the moment if I just have the last part `/regions/:region/:country/:city` and go to `/regions/europe/france` I get a 404 page not found?

```
server.get('/regions/:region/', (req, res) => {
  const actualPage = '/regions'
  const queryParams = {
    region: req.params.region
  }
  app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})

server.get('/regions/:region/:country', (req, res) => {
  const actualPage = '/regions'
  const queryParams = {
    region: req.params.region,
    country: req.params.country
  }
  app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})

server.get('/regions/:region/:country/:city', (req, res) => {
  const actualPage = '/regions'
  const queryParams = {
    region: req.params.region,
    country: req.params.country,
    city: req.params.country
  }
  app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})
```

Comment: You could have all the routes calling the same function e.g. `regionFunction(req, res)` and then build the `queryParams` object in this function based on which params are present...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty much equivalent:

```
const handleRegion = (req, res) => {
  app.render(req, res, '/regions', req.params)
}

server.get('/regions/:region/', handleRegion)
server.get('/regions/:region/:country', handleRegion)
server.get('/regions/:region/:country/:city', handleRegion)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of routes to the [get](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method) method, here is an example:

```
server.get([
    '/regions/:region',
    '/regions/:region/:country',
    '/regions/:region/:country/:city'
], (req, res) => {

    const actualPage = '/regions'

    const queryParams = req.params

    res.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})
```